# Sox does not record

Tags: c#, audio, sox

Trying to record using the following parameters but it does not generate a wav file. When i try same argument manually using cmd it generates a wav file just fine.

```
        string Path = @"C:\Data\sox1441\sox.exe";
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path);
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Data\sox1441\sox.exe";
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        startInfo.Arguments = ("sox -b 24 -r 48k --buffer 8000 -t waveaudio -d apple.wav trim 0 3 -c 8");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Data\sox1441\";
        using (Process soxProc = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            soxProc.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Comment: Do you need that "sox" at the start of the Arguments?

Comment: ProcessStartInfo has a RedirectStandardOutput property that can be used to capture any output of the process you are trying to run, e.g. any errors or messages

Comment: I've tried without "sox" and also tried rearranging other parameters but no luck yet.

Comment: I downloaded sox to test locally, 1) remove "sox" from the arguments, 2) make sure the effect is the final thing in the arguments, e.g. "-b 24 -r 48k --buffer 8000 -t waveaudio -d apple.wav -c 8 trim 0 3"